# How should I handle an errors from server in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a small app, written using ember.js, that talks to REST API using `RESTAdapter` and displaying elements in list using `ArrayController`. When I'm performing a POST request to server and the responds with code 201 (Created) and a model with id the new models is displayed in list. But if server returns code 409 (Conflict) with the payload that looks like this

```
{
   'errors': ['Error description']
}
```

I expect that model will not be added to list, but it isn't so. The model is still added to list, but without ID.

I found out that this model can be removed in multiple ways, but I don't know which of them is right.

So the questions are:

- What is the right way to handle errors in this case (when you are using ArrayController and RESTAdapter)?
- Is it possible to prevent model showing up in list if server returns 4xx code?

Here is code that I use now:

```
App.Usergroup = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.UsergroupsListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['usergroups'],
    allUsergroups: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.usergroups'),
    itemController: 'usergroup'
});

App.UsergroupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        removeGroup: function() {
            var group = this.get('model');
            group.deleteRecord();
            group.save();
        }
    }
});

App.UsergroupsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        addUsergroup: function() {
            var model = this.get('model');
            var group = this.store.createRecord('usergroup', {
                name: model.name,
                description: model.description
            });
            group.save().then(function() {              
            },
            function(error){
                group.rollback();
            });
            this.transitionTo('usergroups.index');
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the template excerpt:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="usergroups">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>User groups list</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <form class="pure-form">
            <fieldset>
                {{input valueBinding="model.name" placeholder="Name"}}
                {{input valueBinding="model.description" placeholder="Description"}}
                <button type="submit" {{action 'addUsergroup'}} class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Add</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="usergroups-list">
    {{#if model}}
    <table class="pure-table pure-table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{id}}</td>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{description}}</td>
                <td><button class="pure-button" {{action "removeGroup"}}><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{else}}
        <p>No user groups.</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, as I found out, errors should be handled in `Route`.

Currently my route looks like this:

```
App.UsergroupsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('usergroup');
    },
    redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
        var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
        loginController.set('attemptedTransition', transition);
        this.transitionTo('login');
    },
    actions: {
        error: function(reason, transition) {
            if (reason.status == 401) {
                this.redirectToLogin(transition);
            }
            else {
                alert('Something went wrong');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It works just fine and does what it should. But now I cannot get what is a reason for placing errors handling in `Route`?

Answer (score 0):

Ember provides an error route and a loading route 
Read more about it here - [Ember error route](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/)

So when the `Usergroup` model throws an error, Ember will look for `UsergroupErrorRoute` or
usergroup/error template.

What you can do is you can have

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="usergroup/error">
{{message}}
<script>
```

where `{{message}}` is transferred from the route